# Check if a date is Sunday

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get 6 days of the week starting from the given date, but the if clause is not taking the 'SUNDAY'.

```
V DATE :=TO_DATE (&H, 'DDMMYYYY');
V1 DATE:=V+6;
V2 VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
  WHILE V<V1 LOOP
    V2:=TO_CHAR(V,'DAY');

    IF V2='SUNDAY' THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TODAY IS SUNDAY');-- IF IS NOT TAKING THE VALUE
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V2||V);

    V:=V+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
FRIDAY   19-SEP-14 
SATURDAY 20-SEP-14 
SUNDAY   21-SEP-14 
MONDAY   22-SEP-14 
TUESDAY  23-SEP-14 
WEDNESDAY24-SEP-14
```

Comment: But why are you shouting?

Comment: ya rite , sorry caps was ON.. sorry again

Comment: So you live in an all-uppercase country?

Comment: :) its just happen in urgency

Comment: @LalitKumarB Since there is no query executed, there is no context switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `TO_CHAR(V,'DAY')` adds spaces after the day, because it pads the day to the longest day name. You can also see this in your output, where all the dates are perfectly aligned underneath each other.

The solution: `Trim` the value:

```
IF TRIM(V2) = 'SUNDAY' THEN
```

This issue is also described here: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/45942/0/

Another nice solution is to use `numeric date language` as an NLS setting to get the day number:

```
V3 := TO_CHAR(V, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''');
```

This way, the TO_CHAR function will return a number (as string) from '1' (Monday) to '7' (Sunday), which is not localized, and is not affected by regional settings when Sunday could be the first day.

`numeric date language` is a special 'language' in which day names are numbers. Because it is actually a day name, you need to use `'DAY'` instead of `'D'`, and for that same reason, it is not affected by the territory. It is a hidden feature which I think is used for testing the localization feature of the data functions. The advantage is that it doesn't depend on installed languages, although I guess that English will also be always available.

Comment: It is better to use `'DY'` format, which only give 3 letters of the days. No issues with extra spaces padded on the right.

Comment: @LalitKumarB But that would mess up the output. Nevertheless a good addition. Thanks. Alternatively, you can use `'numeric date language'` to get the date as a number. I decided to add that to the answer, since Alex Poole already wrote an elaborate answer about `DY`.

Comment: The day *number* is from the `D` element, not `DAY`. And `D` is affected by the `NLS_TERRITORY` rather than the language - it's different between the USA and UK for example, but both use English (mostly!). {more in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212). So your description and code don't quite align...

Comment: @AlexPoole That is what `numeric date language` is for. It is like a special language in which day names are numbers. Because it is actually a day name, you need to use `DAY`, and for that same reason, it is not affected by the territory. It's kinda like a hidden feature. The advantage is that it doesn't depend on installed languages, although I guess that English will also be always available.

Comment: Ohhhh... I misread that as a place holder for a language name, somehow. That's a new one for me. I've only used the (documented!) `D` format and territory to get a consistent value. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `TRIM()` or using the abbreviated form with the `DY` format element, you can also use [the `FM` fill-mode format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) to get the full date name without the padding:

```
V2:=TO_CHAR(V,'FMDAY');

IF V2='SUNDAY' THEN 
...
```

Of course, that does mess up your display since you then use that same `V2` value, so you'd see:

```
FRIDAY19-SEP-14
SATURDAY20-SEP-14
TODAY IS SUNDAY
SUNDAY21-SEP-14
MONDAY22-SEP-14
TUESDAY23-SEP-14
WEDNESDAY24-SEP-14
```

Both `DAY` and `DY` are affected by your NLS settings, so if whoever runs this happens to be in a different locale this might not work as expected; for someone in a French-speaking country, for example, would see `DIMANCHE` which is not equal to the string literal `'SUNDAY'`. You can remove the possible ambiguity by specifying the language to be use:

```
V2:=TO_CHAR(V,'FMDAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
```

It might seem like overkill, but if you're comparing the result rather than just displaying it, it's a bit safer. Since you want to display as well you can get both by doing the `TO_CHAR()` twice:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH;
DECLARE
V DATE :=TO_DATE (&H, 'DDMMYYYY');
V1 DATE:=V+6;
BEGIN
  WHILE V<V1 LOOP
    IF TO_CHAR(V,'FMDAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')='SUNDAY' THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TODAY IS SUNDAY');
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(V,'DAY')||V);

    V:=V+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

VIERNES  19-SEP-14
SÁBADO   20-SEP-14
TODAY IS SUNDAY
DOMINGO  21-SEP-14
LUNES    22-SEP-14
MARTES   23-SEP-14
MIÉRCOLES24-SEP-14
```

The comparison is always in the fixed language, but the display will be in the session language.

You can also do this in plain SQL, apart from easily displaying both the Sunday date and the 'today is Sunday' message; or with a simpler PL/SQL loop. Depends what your real-world use for this is.